# convert first character of string to uppercase using java 8 lambdas only

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, uppercase

I want to create a basic program of converting first character of string to uppercase through lambdas
**Input**

```
singhakash
```

**Output**

```
Singhakash
```

I tried

```
String st = "singhakash";

//approach 1
System.out.print(st.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
st.substring(1).codePoints()
               .forEach(e -> System.out.print((char) e));

System.out.println();

//approach 2
System.out.print(st.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
IntStream.range(0, st.length())
         .filter(i -> i > 0)
         .mapToObj(st::charAt)
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

But for both the cases I have to print the first character seperately.Is there any way I can do that without having a seperate print statement?

Note: I can do that normally by loop or any other approach but I am looking for lambdas only solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really have to use lambda?

Comment: @dguay yes I can only use lambdas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
String st = "singhakash";
IntStream.range(0, st.length())
         .mapToObj(i -> i == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(st.charAt(i)) : st.charAt(i))
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do it would be

```
String result = Character.toUpperCase(st.charAt(0))+st.substring(1);
```

If you feel like you have to optimize it, i.e. reduce the number of copying operations (instead of letting the JVM do it), you may use:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(st);
sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));
String result=sb.toString();
```

But if it really has to be done using the fancy new Java 8 feature, you can use

```
String result=IntStream.concat(
    IntStream.of(st.codePointAt(0)).map(Character::toUpperCase), st.codePoints().skip(1) )
  .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();
```

This solution will even handle supplementary code points correctly, so it has even an advantage over the simple solutions (though it would not be too hard to makes these supplementary code point aware too).

If you want to print directly, you can use

```
IntStream.concat(
    IntStream.of(st.codePointAt(0)).map(Character::toUpperCase), st.codePoints().skip(1))
 .forEach(cp -> System.out.print(Character.toChars(cp)));
```

Comment: I [committed](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/46efc8851f4bb7777da9db7991a9a8378227dcb2) `mapFirst`/`mapLast` methods to my library which apply the given mapper function to the first/last stream element only (though current implementation is not very optimal). Now it's as simple as `IntStreamEx.ofCodePoints(str).mapFirst(Character::toUpperCase).codePointsToString()`. I don't know whether such feature is actually useful though...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: there will be different opinions about that, I guess ;^)

Answer (score 2):

`String` is immutable in Java. Just uppercase the first character, and append the rest. Something like,

```
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(st.charAt(0)) + st.substring(1));
```

Comment: thnaks for the answer but I was practicing lambdas so for that I am looking for lambda answer.I know it would be much easier with your approach but I am bound to use lambdas only

Answer (score 0):

`st.replaceFirst(st.subSequence(0,1).toString(),st.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase().codePoints().forEach(e -> System.out.print((char)e));`